# Google Calendar list of events with timeMin in calendar's timeZone

Tags: timezone, google-calendar-api

## The Requirement

I can retrieve list of google-calendar events following this reference: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

How can I get list of all the events between `2017-03-30T14:30:00` and `2017-03-30T15:30:00` **according to the calendar's timeZone**?

## My investigation

There are optional parameters `timeMin`, `timeMax`. The problem is that they should have one of the following formats (RFC3339 timestamp):

1. `2017-03-30T14:30:00Z`, here  `Z` stand for Zulu = UTC timeZone
2. `2017-03-30T14:30:00+03`, here `+03` stands for the timeZone shift comparing to UTC

In both cases I have to get the calendar's timeZone (how can I get it in format I need with offset, e.g. `-04`, `+00`, `+03`?) and then perform some extra calculations/manipulations.

Obviously in my case I would prefer just to pass the values without mentioning the timeZone and make API use the calendar's timeZone.

There is another optional parameter `timeZone` but this is the timeZone that will be used in the response, not in the filter. The default is the calendar's timeZone which is good for me.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the way to apply GC (Google Calendar) TZ on a datetime:

```
from dateutil import tz
from datetime import datetime
tzinfo = tz.gettz(default_calendar['timeZone'])

# Option1: create date without TZ and then apply GC TZ using astimezone:
dt = datetime(2018,7,3,14,30,0)
dt_in_gc_tz = dt.astimezone(tzinfo) # 2018-07-03 14:30:00+03:00

# Option2: just create dateTime with GC TZ:
dt_in_gc_tz = datetime(2018, 7,3,14,30,0, tzinfo=tzinfo) # 2018-07-03 14:30:00+03:00

# Convert to RFC3339 timestamp string:
dt_in_gc_tz.isoformat() # '2018-07-03T14:30:00+03:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the `'q'` property for this. Instead, use `timeMin` and `timeMax` with timeMin being the earlier date. In the [try-it](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) format looks like this:

[image]

Comment: In my question I mentioned that the problem is to get it in TimeZone of the calendar. Thank you, but your answer is in UTC (Z stand for Zulu = UTC timeZone)

Answer (score 0):

```
        const moment = require('moment-timezone');

        const timeMin = moment(start_time).toISOString();
        const timeMax = moment(end_time).toISOString();

        oauth2Client.setCredentials({ refresh_token });

        const token = await oauth2Client.getAccessToken();
        const response = await axios.get(
            `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/${email}/events?key=${config.get('service:google:api_key')}&timeMin=${timeMin}&timeMax=${timeMax}`, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token.res.data.access_token}`
            }
        });
```